# register service worker with nextjs application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, service-worker, next.js

I'm a newbie to `nextjs` and working on a small application where I want to provide an offline support but I'm not been able to register service worker.

throwing `Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script` this error.

following is my code...
and my **service-worker.js** is at the root of `nextjs` application.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('../service-worker.js')
            .catch(err => console.log('err', err))
    }
}
```

do I need to configure server i.e. (server.js) in some way to serve that file..?

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

var routes = require('./router');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare()
    .then(() => {
       const server = express();

       server.use('/edit', routes);

       server.get('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res));

       server.listen(3000, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('http://localhost:3000');
       });
     })
     .catch((ex) => {
        console.log(ex.stack);
        process.exit(1);
    })
```

if yes then how should I do it..?

the directory structure is shown in following image link.
[directory structure](https://ibb.co/eBTb7K)

Answer (score 5):

You need to serve your `service-worker` file as a static file to achieve that.

See the reference [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/85769c3d3296cdcddc0fb36f05058c8e451ca57f/examples/with-sw-precache/server.js), `app.serveStatic(req, res, filePath)` line 19.

You can take a look on the complete example [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/85769c3d3296cdcddc0fb36f05058c8e451ca57f/examples/with-sw-precache).

Answer (score 1):

move `service-worker.js` file in `server` folder and add following line

```
server.use('/service-worker.js', express.static(__dirname + '/service-worker.js'));
```

in `server.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

**Service worker registration in Nextjs project**

Put the service worker file in the public directory.

[image]

Inside your _app.js write below code :

```
componentDidMount(){
    if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
            navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
        }
}
```